# Separate ints from a file separated by a semicolon into different digits in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

I need to get an input from a file. This input is any binary number of any length where the digits are separated by a semicolon like this:

> 0; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0;

What I would do is pass the file to a variable like

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
        File = line;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

But I'm not sure what data type I would make the variable `File` be. After this I'd have to store the digits in an `array` or `vector`.

Comment: Once you have your line, you need to parse it, it's one string with all the values on that line.

Comment: _what data type_ to use to store _any binary number of any length_ is tricky. Do you need to do calculations using the number? If not, store it in a `std::string`. If you do, you probably need a BigNum library.
Btw, your example does not match the text. The numbers in the example are separated by `; ` not `;`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I do need to do operations with the numbers later. And what do you mean by the numbers in the example are separated by " `;` not `;` " Aren't those two semi colons?

Comment: The first is a semicolon followed by a space. For operations on numbers of any length, search for BigNum or Big Number libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, what you have to do, is to split your `string` by your delimiter (in your case, delimiter is `"; "`). It can be done by using `std::string::find` method, which returns index of character/string we look for, and  `std::string::substr` method, which returns substring based on provided begin index (got from `find`) and number of characters to read (we read only `0` or `1`, so length will always be 1). Once you extract desired substring, you can convert it to data type which suit your needs.

Below is simple example how to create `vector` of `bool`'s based on such `string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string line = "0; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; "; // In your case, 'line' will contain getline() result
    std::vector<bool> bits;
    std::size_t lastPos = 0;

    if(!line.empty()) bits.push_back(line.substr(0, 1) == "1");

    while((lastPos = line.find("; ", lastPos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        lastPos += 2; // +2 because we don't want to read delimiter
        if(lastPos < line.size()) bits.push_back(line.substr(lastPos, 1) == "1");
    }

    for(auto bit : bits)
    {
        std::cout << bit << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
0
1
0
```

Comment: Thanks. Searching around I found about delimeter. I got to more or less what you wrote but yours seems much cleaner to what I've got.
After that I need to store the numbers in a vector of type `int`. Would I be able to do that with the `stringstream` library?

Something like
`int i;

for (auto bit : bits)

 {

     stringstream StringToInt(bit);

     StringToInt >> i;

     intVector.puch_back(i);

 } `

Comment: @LuisDelBarrio You want to store each `bit` as `int` or create `int` based on all `bit`s?

Comment: @Rhalthin if possible I would want to store each `bit` as `int`

Comment: @LuisDelBarrio Then you can simply change elements type of vector `bits` from `std::vector<bool> bits` to `std::vector<int> bits`. `bool` value we push back into vector will be then implicitly converted to `int`.

Comment: Oh, I just read your answer a bit slower now. But yeah, how would I then store it as any data type I want to? 
Sorry, I'm just kinda new to c++

Comment: @LuisDelBarrio It depends on data type you need.

Comment: Oh ok. Great. Thanks for the help. Gonna try implementing it into my code and see.

Comment: @LuisDelBarrio For _any binary number of any length_ you should probably not try to implement it yourself. At least I wouldn't since there are libraries like _The GNU MP Bignum Library_ to handle that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks but I don't think I'll need to use it. When I mean "any length" I mean anything between 1 to 20 digits (but it can be anything). This is just for a small project.

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok, I'll give it a try too.

Answer (score 0):

Since the *any length* requirement doesn't apply (noticed in the comments), here's my take on it. It's a class template (`binreader<T>`) where `T` is the numeric type you'd like to extract from the file, like `uint32_t` (or `int32_t` for signed values).

**binreader.hpp**

```
#ifndef binreader_hpp_8ac51dd6_fe5f_11e8_a64e_90b11c0c0ff8
#define binreader_hpp_8ac51dd6_fe5f_11e8_a64e_90b11c0c0ff8

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>
#include <stdexcept>

// class template to read a line from a stream as a binary value and convert it
// to a user supplied type
template<typename T>
class binreader {
    T m_value; // the extracted value
public:
    // the number of bits in the type
    static constexpr size_t bits = sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT;

    binreader() : m_value(0) {} // default constructor

    // input stream operator for reading a line
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, binreader& br) {
        std::string line;

        if(std::getline(is, line)) {
            T rv = 0; // the variable we'll populate with the extracted bits
            size_t bitcount=0; // overflow guard

            // loop through all characters in the line
            for(auto ch : line) {
                // just discard anything not '0' or '1'
                if(ch!='0' && ch!='1') continue;

                // check if we've already extracted the max number of bits
                if(++bitcount > bits)
                    throw std::overflow_error(
                        "Too many bits (>"+std::to_string(bits)+") for binreader type"
                    );

                // store the extracted bit
                rv <<= 1;       // shift up 1 step
                rv |= (ch-'0'); // OR the found 0 or 1
            }
            // a successful read, set the value of this binreader
            br.m_value = rv;
        } // else is.failbit will be set and the outer loop will stop
        return is;
    }

    // an output stream operator to print a binreader value
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const binreader& br) {
        os << br.m_value;
        return os;
    }

    // conversion to T for convenience
    operator T () const { return m_value; }
};

#endif
```

**Example usage:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "binreader.hpp"

// a test function template to open a file, extract and store the values
// in a std::vector<T> that will be returned to the caller

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> trytype(const std::string& filename) {
    std::vector<T> rv;

    // open file
    std::ifstream fi(filename);

    if(fi) { // opened successfully?
        // declare a binreader variable of a wanted type
        // suitable to fit the binary numbers in the file
        binreader<T> value;

        std::cout << "Reading at most " << value.bits << " bits\n";
        try {
            // extract the value on one line
            while(fi >> value) {
                // store the value to return using the
                // conversion operator T ()
                rv.push_back(value);
            }
        } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
            std::clog << " ERROR: " << ex.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
    return rv;
}

// function template to display values in a container
// (a std::vector<T> that is returned from trytype<T>)
template<typename C>
void display(const C& extracted_values) {
    std::cout << " Extracted values:\n";
    for(auto v : extracted_values) {
        std::cout << " " << v << "\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // make a vector of all the command line arguments
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);

    // open all files given as command line arguments and
    // try to extract binary values using different types
    // and call display() to print the values
    for(const auto& file : args) {
        display( trytype<uint64_t>(file) );
        display( trytype<int64_t>(file) );
        display( trytype<uint32_t>(file) );
        display( trytype<int32_t>(file) );
        display( trytype<uint16_t>(file) );
        display( trytype<int16_t>(file) );
        display( trytype<uint8_t>(file) );
        display( trytype<int8_t>(file) );
    }
}
```

Example file:

```
0; 1; 1; 0;
1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1;
1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1;
1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1;
1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1;
```

Example output:

```
Reading at most 64 bits
 Extracted values:
 6
 235
 60395
 3958107115
 16999940616948018155
Reading at most 64 bits
 Extracted values:
 6
 235
 60395
 3958107115
 -1446803456761533461
Reading at most 32 bits
 ERROR: Too many bits (>32) for binreader type
 Extracted values:
 6
 235
 60395
 3958107115
Reading at most 32 bits
 ERROR: Too many bits (>32) for binreader type
 Extracted values:
 6
 235
 60395
 -336860181
Reading at most 16 bits
 ERROR: Too many bits (>16) for binreader type
 Extracted values:
 6
 235
 60395
Reading at most 16 bits
 ERROR: Too many bits (>16) for binreader type
 Extracted values:
 6
 235
 -5141
Reading at most 8 bits
 ERROR: Too many bits (>8) for binreader type
 Extracted values:

 ▒
Reading at most 8 bits
 ERROR: Too many bits (>8) for binreader type
 Extracted values:

 ▒
```

Note that the 8 bit types will print characters instead of numbers, but they are just as valid for arithmetic operations. `static_cast` to a bigger type to display their values.

Comment: Oh wow, that was honestly a bit overwhelming. The previous answer worked for what I was trying to do, but I'll try to understand more closely how yours works and might try implementing it to my program. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I hope you'll find something useful in there. If anything is unclear, just ask and I'll update the answer.